# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

Tags: gtk, pantheon

Once upon a time, I've installed Pantheon desktop on Ubuntu 14.04.

And then I decided to use vanilla desktop, Unity.

So I've removed all things related with Pantheon. I can't remember the exact command, but it seems like:

```
sudo apt-get remove pantheon*
```

When I open some apps which run with GUI from terminal, an error, a warning or a message is shown.

```
$ gedit
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
$ wireshark
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
$ nautilus
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

It seems it does not affect to the actual behavior of the system. But it is really annoying to me.

Is there anyone who can give me a tiny hint to solve this problem?

Comment: Install pantheon and the error will go away.

Comment: You will always see this message with non-gtk3 apps. It's harmless and you can ignore it. |Elementary OS Freya

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem! If you run the following:

```
env | grep -i gtk
```

And see the module in your path like mine:

```
GTK_MODULES=pantheon-filechooser-module:overlay-scrollbar
```

Then it means it's being set somewhere to use the pantheon which needs to be removed. I did a quick grep and found the following:

```
/etc/profile.d/pantheon-filechooser-module.sh:export GTK_MODULES=pantheon-filechooser-module
```

So did:

```
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/pantheon-filechooser-module.sh
```

Finally - I saved my GTK_MODULES variable without the filechooser in my current session so not to have to restart: (obviously yours will be different to mine)

```
GTK_MODULES="overlay-scrollbar"
```

Job Done.

Comment: In elementaryOS I had to type it like this: `set GTK_MODULES gail:atk-bridge`

Comment: Where ATK-Bridge is just another module like overlay scrollbar, in the answer.